# how can i solve error of Imgproc in OpenCv Version 4.1.2?

Tags: opencv, android

i get error in Imgproc in my project.
i'm using android studio version 3.5.3 & OpenCv  Version 4.1.2.
here's my Gradle code.
i want to use Imgproc in my project but when i write Imgproc i get error

````
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camscanner"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':scanlibrary')
}```

how i use Imgproc in my project
please Help.
````

Answer (score 2):

You can try [JavaCPP-presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets).

Add some dependencies on `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.2-1.5.2'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.2-1.5.2', classifier: "android-arm"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.2-1.5.2', classifier: "android-arm64"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.2-1.5.2', classifier: "android-x86"
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.2-1.5.2', classifier: "android-x86_64"
}
```

You can use `org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_imgproc` or `org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc`

[Here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/latest/index.html) you'll find the javadocs